# Bootstrap Modal Popup Video hidden under Black Overlay

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project where I am facing an issue with Bootstrap Modal Video Popup. A black overlay seems above the Modal and unclickable. Screenshot attached. Could anyone provide help on this?

```
<div
    _ngcontent-ymu-c8=""
    class="pageTitle"
>
    <div
        _ngcontent-ymu-c8=""
        class="viewDemo"
    >
        <ul _ngcontent-ymu-c8="">
            <li
                _ngcontent-ymu-c8=""
                class="no-padding-right-left"
            >
                <h2
                    _ngcontent-ymu-c8=""
                    class="padding-right"
                >
                    <em _ngcontent-ymu-c8="">Setup Advanced Mileage</em>
                </h2>
            </li>

            <li
                _ngcontent-ymu-c8=""
                class="margin-top-7"
            >
                <app-video-icon
                    _ngcontent-ymu-c8=""
                    _nghost-ymu-c9=""
                >
                    <a
                        _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                        class="videoLink1"
                        data-target="#myModal"
                        data-toggle="modal"
                    >
                        <span _ngcontent-ymu-c9="">Watch Video</span>

                        <img
                            _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                            alt=""
                            src="assets/svg-icons/new-video-icon.svg"
                        >
                    </a>

                    <div
                        _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                        class="clear"
                    ></div>

                    <div
                        _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                        class="modal fade"
                        id="myModal"
                        role="dialog"
                        tabindex="-1"
                        style="display: none;"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                    >
                        <div
                            _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                            class="modal-dialog"
                            role="document"
                            style="max-width: 970px;  margin: 1.75rem auto;"
                        >
                            <div
                                _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                                class="modal-content"
                            >
                                <div
                                    _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                                    class="modal-header"
                                >
                                    <button
                                        _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                                        aria-label="Close"
                                        class="close"
                                        data-dismiss="modal"
                                        type="button"
                                    >
                                        <span
                                            _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                            class="video-close"
                                        >×</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>

                                <div
                                    _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                                    class="modal-body"
                                >
                                    <div
                                        _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                                        style="background:white;width:100%;margin:auto;"
                                    >
                                        <iframe
                                            _ngcontent-ymu-c9=""
                                            allowfullscreen=""
                                            frameborder="0"
                                            height="100%"
                                            mozallowfullscreen=""
                                            webkitallowfullscreen=""
                                            width="100%"
                                            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLugzlMICZR8iumkWoAbGrO7wxT4rXnIMi"
                                            class="video-height-youtube"
                                        ></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </app-video-icon>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Bootstrap Modal Popup to play video]

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using? I've made a codeply: https://www.codeply.com/p/6jvdBH8Syl and fore me it is working.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using Bootstrap 4.4